# Ruby on Rails - can't access datetime model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created a model that has 3 string columns and a datetime.  Everything is running in SQLite3 and I can view the records in my table just fine using Lita.

I'm trying to display the values in a page (index action) using code like this:

From the debug I get a result like this:

--- !ruby/object:LifeCycle 
attributes: 
  eventType: Order
  created_at: "2111359287.23037"
  timeId: "2455364.89983796"
  eventId: "98765"
  updated_at: "2111359287.23037"
  lifeCycleId: "12345"
  id: "1"
attributes_cache: {}

But whenever I try to access the event timeId - i' getting a nil value.  This is true if i try to run debug on just that field debug(lifeCycle.timeId), or call a function on it.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out problem - in datetime fields in database were not create properly when adding record w/ Lita.  Redid it w/ sqlite manager for Firefox and everything works great.